# Radio button in Qt GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using Qt5.2.1 and I made a program to do some stuff. In it I added a radio button (named 'others') i want that when the user clicks this button a line edit pops up besides it and lets the user enter some stuff inside it. when the user clicks another radio button, this line edit goes away. How do I do this?

Please please help me!

Comment: @RedAlert the thing is I have added the radio button through the Qt designer so I haven't really coded anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I want that when the user clicks this button (...).  How do I do this?

[QRadioButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qradiobutton.html)

> Whenever a button is switched on or off it emits the `toggled() signal`. Connect to this signal if you want to trigger an action each
>   time the button changes state. Use `isChecked()` to see if a particular button is selected.

You can also write a wrapper over `QRadioButtons` so you can connect their `toggled(bool)` signals to single slot `toggled(int)` of this wrapper using i.e. [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html). Then you can manage all this logic in such wrapper:

```
void RadioHelper::initialize( const std::vector<
                                   QSharedPointer<RadioHelperEntry> >& entries)
{
    entries_ = entries;
    mapper_.reset(new QSignalMapper(this));
    EntriesIterator it = entries_.begin();

    int i = 0;
    while ( it!=entries_.end())
    {
       connect(( *it)->button_, SIGNAL( toggled(bool)), mapper_.data(), 
                                                                   SLOT(map()));
       mapper_->setMapping( ( *it)->button_, (int)( *it)->mode_);
       it++;
       i++;
    }
    connect( mapper_.data(), SIGNAL( mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL( toggled(int)));
    connect( this, SIGNAL( toggled(int)), this, SLOT( updateValue(int)));
}

void RadioHelper::updateValue( int v)
{
    value_ = v;
    emit valueChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was looking for

ui->radio_button->setvisible(false);

^ helped me get the desired result